# How do I update a javascript variable from controller?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the model from the view with this:

```
<script>
    Module.getModel(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))
</script>
```

Which calls this:

```
var getModel = function(model) {
    vModel= model;
};
```

This works to initially get the model, but I need to update one of the model values via dialog ajax.

```
var loc = $("#Location").val();
$.ajax({
    url: $("#root").attr("href") + "Home/SetLocation",
    context: $(this),
    type: 'POST',
    data: { location: loc },
    success: function() {
         $(this).dialog("close");
         reloadGrid();
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("There was a problem updating your Location.");
    }
});
```

The controller action saves the location to profile and redirects to "Index" action:

```
public ActionResult SetLocation(string location)
{
    _dashboardTasks.SaveLocationToProfile(location);            
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Which updates the model with the new profile information and returns it to the view:

```
public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel homeViewModel)
{
    SetUserLocation(homeViewModel);
    return View(homeViewModel);
}
```

At this point the breakpoint on the first code block is hit again, but the function for it, `getModel`, is never called and the javascript model is never updated. So the `success` function which calls for the grid to reload, reuses the old data instead of the new data.

**How can I update `vModel` with the value changed in the controller?**

Do I have to add a declaration to the `success` function explicitly redefining the value?

```
success: function() {
    $(this).dialog("close");
    vModel.Location = loc;
    reloadGrid();
},
```

This works, but I don't understand why the model is not being updated with the current code.

Comment: _and redirects to "Index" action_? No it doesn't. Ajax calls stay on the same page. Unclear exactly what your doing but your `SetLocation()` method needs to return json or a partial view that you can use to update the existing page

Comment: It _does_ redirect to the "Index" action, so do you mean that it _should't_? The "Index" page is actually the same page.

Comment: If it then your calling it twice, once in the ajax call (which does not redirect) and again because its a link and you have not cancelled it. And please change `url: $("#root").attr("href") + "Home/SetLocation",` to `url: '@Ul.Action("SetLocation", "Home"),` - you should never hard code url's like that.

Comment: I'm not understanding. The ajax calls `SetLocation`, which redirects to `Index`. What are you saying is being called twice? I can't do anything about the url. It's that way because of the way the website is accessed on the company server.

Comment: The ajax call **does not** redirect to `Index().` You have not shown the relevant code (how you are actually trigger the function) but  assuming its `$('yourLink').click(function(e) { // ajax })` then add `e.preventDefault();` as the first line of code to understand whats really happening. If you don't cancel the click event of the link, then you are doing both the standard redirect (i.e. the default action of a link) and the ajax call.